# wget - keep the files with same name

Tags: bash, scripting

I am downloading some files from database by using wget but some of the files in database named same. So, when I download 2 files with the same name, the files break. I wonder if there is a way to keep both files. For example I downloaded file named a.png and I download another different file but with the same name and change the name into a 2.png

Simply I just need something that recognize the file with the same name and gives different name to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ...

thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wget -nd` option to make sure it clobbers existing file.

As per `man wget`:

```
-nd
--no-directories
  Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.  With this 
  option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, without 
  clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, **the filenames will get
  extensions .n**).
```

Also I like to add this:

> When running Wget without -N, -nc, -r, or -p, downloading the same file in the same directory will result in the
>              original copy of file being preserved and the second copy being named file.1.  If that file is downloaded yet
>              again, the third copy will be named file.2, and so on.  (This is also the behavior with -nd, even if -r or -p are
>              in effect.)  When -nc is specified, this behavior is suppressed, and Wget will refuse to download newer copies of
>              file.

Comment: wget -c -nd -O /Users/myUserName/Pictures/"$category"/"$title".png http://www.myWebsite.com/$i.png it is in a loop and I get category and title from somewhere else.

Comment: Oh don't use `-O` to utilize clobbering.

Comment: that's what I was afraid to hear. so I have to change the logic now. thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to do it with "-O". So, I kept that there and modified the program. I checked if the name of the file exist before I download. If it is exit I download the file like this "name$i.png". And also, I wrote the name of the file, which is exist, into .txt file. So, later on I will change them manually.